# pandas dataframe: error joining

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe

I've got these two dataframes:

```
1) df
STATCODE    OCCDATE     COWNNUM     AGNTNUM
IF          20130725    50033901    61002624
IF          20130725    50033901    61002624
IF          20130725    50033901    61002624
IF          20130725    50033901    61002624

2) dfCus
CLNTNUM     CLTTYPE     CLTSEX
50033901    P           M
50033901    P           M
50055927    P           F
```

I run this code to create columns with a standard naming, and I want to join the dataframes on that column.

```
df.index.names = ['ID']
dfCus.index.names = ['ID']
df['CLNTNUM'] = df.index
dfCus['CLNTNUM'] = dfCus.index
data = df.join(dfCus, how='inner', on='CLNTNUM')
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'CLNTNUM'], dtype='object')
```

Can you help me understand what's wrong?
Thanks
AC

Comment: `join` requires you to specify the lhs and rhs suffixes when the values clash, in this case it maybe better to do `df.merge(dfCus, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), parameter `how='inner'` is by default, so can be omited:

```
data = df.merge(dfCus, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

and this code can be omited:

```
df.index.names = ['ID']
dfCus.index.names = ['ID']
df['CLNTNUM'] = df.index
dfCus['CLNTNUM'] = dfCus.index
```

EDIT1:

By sample it looks like you need join on columns `COWNNUM` in `df` and  `CLNTNUM` in `dfCus` - but you have duplicated values, so output is:

```
print (df)
  STATCODE   OCCDATE   COWNNUM   AGNTNUM
0       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624
1       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624
2       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624
3       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624

print (dfCus)
    CLNTNUM CLTTYPE CLTSEX
0  50033901       P      M
1  50033901       P      M
2  50055927       P      F

df = df.merge(dfCus, left_on='COWNNUM', right_on='CLNTNUM')
print (df)
  STATCODE   OCCDATE   COWNNUM   AGNTNUM   CLNTNUM CLTTYPE CLTSEX
0       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
1       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
2       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
3       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
4       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
5       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
6       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
7       IF  20130725  50033901  61002624  50033901       P      M
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, i.e. using `lsuffix`:

```
data = df.join(dfCus, how='inner', on='CLNTNUM',lsuffix='_l')
```